# How can java object from java code be passed to R script?

Tags: java, r

i'm curious is it possible to path java object (in any type (java/class/jar)) to REngine? till now i'm successfully executing an operation from java to R or vice versa. for example: i have my custom jar files which i'm using in RStudio,  i wish to have same opportunity from java code as well. 
[image]

above code is from RStudio

bellow code is from java

```
    String javaVector="c(1,2,3,4,5)";
    Rengine rengine = new Rengine(new String[]{"-no-save"}, false, null);
    rengine.eval("rVector <-"+javaVector);
    rengine.eval("meanVal=mean(rVector)");
    double mean = rengine.eval("meanVal").asDouble();
    REXP rexp = rengine.eval("meanVal");
    System.out.println("Mean of given vector is <-"+mean);
    rengine.eval(String.format("greeting <- '%s'", "Hello R World"));
    REXP result = rengine.eval("greeting");
    System.out.println("Greeting from R: "+result.asString());
```

Answer (score 0):

i will answer my question. if someone is interested in answer. so to path java object from java code to R script you can do next:  first pick the object you want to work with, for example :

```
public class RAccess{
static public Object getObject(String id){
    return test;
}

static TestClass test = new TestClass();
```

}

```
public class TestClass{
String message;
public void setMessage(String value){

    message = value;
}
```

}

after evaluate R script exactly like you do it in R console or RStudio, just put  it in curly braces.

```
REXP x = re.eval(rCode3);

    System.out.println(RAccess.test.message);

    static String rCode3 =
            "{ \n" +
                    "library(rJava) \n" +
                    ".jinit() \n" +
                    "obj <- .jcall(\"jriTest/RAccess\", \"Ljava/lang/Object;\", \"getObject\", \"id\") \n" +
                    ".jcall(obj, \"V\", \"setMessage\", \"hello from R\") \n" +
                    "}";
```

jriTest is a package name.